# Autoreleasepool in background queue for Realm

Tags: objective-c, realm

In the example project of RealmCocoa:

```
// Multi-threading
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    RLMRealm *otherRealm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
    RLMResults *otherResults = [Dog objectsInRealm:otherRealm where:@"name contains 'Rex'"];
    NSLog(@"Number of dogs: %li", (unsigned long)otherResults.count);
});
```

In the website docs:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_queue_create("background", 0), ^{
    @autoreleasepool {
        Dog *theDog = [[Dog objectsWhere:@"age == 1"] firstObject];
        RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
        [realm beginWriteTransaction];
        theDog.age = 3;
        [realm commitWriteTransaction];
    }
});
```

- Why doesn't the example project have autoreleasepool?
- Should the example project's code also include an autoreleasepool?
- Which one of these usage is more appropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why doesn't the example project have autoreleasepool?

It’s an oversight.

> Should the example project's code also include an autoreleasepool?

Yes.

> Which one of these usage is more appropriate?

The latter. As [Realm’s documentation on threading states](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#threading), all use of Realm from background threads should be contained within explicit autorelease pools.

Comment: I think it'd be better if the documentation has some "for dummies" section to explain these things in more basic words. Because when I first read it, I didn't understand the exact meaning. Thanks for the answer!